# Next Js dynamic routes for index.tsx ssr

Tags: next.js, locale

I have set up some locales
In next.config.js

`i18n: { locales: ["en", "en-us", "en-gb", "en-au", "en-ca", "en-ie", "es-es", "es-co", "es-ar", "es-pe", "es-ve",  "es-cl",  "es-ec",  "es-bo"], defaultLocale: "en", },`

and as well as a variable
`export const locales= ["en", "en-us", "en-gb", "en-au", "en-ca", "en-ie", "es-es", "es-co", "es-ar", "es-pe", "es-ve", "es-cl", "es-ec",  "es-bo"];`

For each locale i want to have a separate index file. At the moment i have set up `pages/[locale].tsx` next to `pages/index.tsx`

in [locale].tsx i have this set up.

```
import { getArticles } from "../utils/db/serverDb";
import ArticlesHome from "@/components/home/ArticlesHome";
import {  locales } from "@/utils/staticInfo";


export default function Home(props: { [key: string]: string }) {
  const articles: { [key: string]: any } = JSON.parse(props.articles);

  return (
    <>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.articleWrapper}>
          <ArticlesHome articles={articles} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ locale }: { locale: string }) {
  //get country initials from locale
  const country = locale !== "en" ? locale.split("-")[1] : "gb";
  //get number of articles from required country
  const articles = await getArticles(`${country}`, 3);
  return {
    props: {
      articles,
    },
    revalidate: 3600,
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
     let paths:{[params:string]: {[locale:string]:string}}[] = [];

     locales.forEach((locale) => {
       // generate paths for each locale
       paths.push({ params: { locale: locale } });
     });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

What set up do i need for index.tsx ? Should it be just rederecting ?
at the moment i have my index.tsx the same as [locale].tsx and when it builds it builds paths as en/en, en/en-gb/, en/en-ir, en/es-es and so on...
I was expecting en, en-gb, en-ir and so on...

It all works but i think that there is something really  bad as i have no idea how to deal with index.tsx what should be in there and why it builds default locale with all the other locales

I tried finding solutions on google and talked to chatGPT but all i could find was articles about how to do do dynamic pages like posts/[article].js and chat was giving code which was not working. I could not find a solution how to dynamically  set up index.

Answer (score 1):

### Redirect to Dynamic Path

You can try combine both server side redirection with get static paths and making one dynamic file eg. **[locale].tsx or [locale]/index.tsx** the solution should be to redirect in getStaticProps. From documentation:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://...`)
  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
        // statusCode: 301
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

However keep in mind that you will need to remove the i18n prefix from url manually, you can rather remove it in useEffect or seek for some other solution, because thats the correct i18n behaviour.

### i18N

Maybe your structure is a little bit short for what is you are trying to achieve.

How does it work - it adds the prefix to every route including dynamic routes and pass locale to context so you can handle correct version of content from your source. So every route for example pages/index.tsx will have all versions of the page with a **** "/en, /en-gb etc..." as soon as you added [locale].tsx it makes the following routes **paths** "/en, /en-gb..." and because you also enabled the i18n it will make this routes with a prefix as well.

Finally if your requirements are not tight, you can create some another parent eg. /articles.

The code would be similar to yours but without getStaticPaths.
As all locales paths will be handled by i18n.

```
 import { getArticles } from "../utils/db/serverDb";
import ArticlesHome from "@/components/home/ArticlesHome";
import {  locales } from "@/utils/staticInfo";


export default function Articles(props: { [key: string]: string }) {
  const articles: { [key: string]: any } = JSON.parse(props.articles);

  return (
    <>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.articleWrapper}>
          <ArticlesHome articles={articles} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ locale }: { locale: string }) {
  //get country initials from locale
  // HERE You Will handle the load of localized articles.
  const country = locale !== "en" ? locale.split("-")[1] : "gb";
  //get number of articles from required country
  const articles = await getArticles(`${country}`, 3);
  return {
    props: {
      articles,
    },
    revalidate: 3600,
  };
}
```

### Another Aproach

It seems like you want to have a separate index file for each locale and serve the correct index file based on the user's locale. Instead of having separate index files for each locale, you can serve a single index file and use server-side redirection to the correct locale index file based on the user's locale.

To achieve this, you can update your **pages/[locale]/index.tsx** or **pages/[locale].tsx** file to perform server-side redirection using the getServerSideProps function. And add the redirect rather in getStaticProps or getServerSideProps.

Here's how you can modify your index.tsx file:

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const IndexPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.replace(`/${router.locale}`);
  }, [router]);

  return null;
};

export default IndexPage;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { locale } = context;
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: `/${locale}`,
      permanent: false,
    },
  };
};
```

This setup will perform a server-side redirection to the correct locale index file based on the user's locale. It will redirect users to the corresponding [locale].tsx page when they visit the root path of your site.

Make sure to remove the getStaticProps and getStaticPaths functions from index.tsx, as they are not required in this setup. Keep these functions only in [locale].tsx file.

Keep in mind that the i18n module in Next.js is designed to handle internationalization, and locale paths are used to serve content based on the user's locale. While the two concepts are related, it's important not to confuse them when configuring your application. In your case, using server-side redirection with the i18n module should help achieve the desired behavior. Also the behaviour of "en/en, en/en-gb/, en/en-ir, en/es-es" is expected as the i18n module is prepend the locale from documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Read Sub-path Routing paragrpah.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I figured out that i had a super bad approach to this. I made a dropdown button with locale choices and based on a choice i am updating the url. 
I thought that if i didnt specify paths of all locales it  wouldnt be served staticaly.
But now i see that they are.